# Call to undefined relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two tables departments and course, and I have defined a relationship between them but I received this error message:

> Call to undefined relationship in laravel

Can anyone tell me please where's the problem?

Model Code:

```
public function course()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Course','departments_id','id');
}
```

Model Department:

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Departments','departments_id');
}
```

Comment: And where are you getting this problem? What exactly the errors says? What exact version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [departments] on model [App\Course]. laravel 5.4

Comment: So as you see you get error for `departments` and you don't have such relationship - you have `department` relationship. So you `department` instead of `departments` and you won't have this error

Comment: Please also provide table structures for course and department to get an specific answer

Comment: public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Departments','departments_id');
    }
show the same errors Call to undefined relationship [name] on model [App\Course].

Comment: Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->float('credit');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->integer('department_id');
            $table->string('semester');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });

Comment: department table
  Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('code');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: Please can you show how are you calling the relations? it seems your relation is okay, then it may be in your calling code.

Comment: please see above code i have uploaded it .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So problem is so clear. Either in your Course model you have to rename the function `department` to `departments`, or to make a new one with the correct name.

Answer (score 5):

in my case, i used:

```
::with('boards')
```

i just changed it to :

```
::with(['boards'])
```

with brackets

in my department Model:

```
public function boards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Board::class);
}
```

Comment: Same issue I got :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all little correction in schema `$table->integer('department_id');`  should be `$table->unsignedInteger('department_id');`

And the problem is - in your migration column name is `department_id` but in your relation you have written `departments_id` there is a extra **S!**

just correct the column name from model.